# React - TypeError: myCart.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm a rookie at React, I want to exercise what I've learnt so far by building a shopping cart application but it throws this error: `TypeError: myCart.map is not a function`

the related code is here:
1- this is the state of myCart: `const [myCart, setMyCart] = useState([]);`
2- handler function for adding products to the cart:

```
function handleAddToCart(product) {
    setMyCart( myCart => [...myCart, product]);
    setProducts( products.map(prod => prod.name === product.name ? {...prod, quantity: prod.quantity > 0 ? prod.quantity -1 : 0 } : prod));
  }
```

3- passing the handler to ListOfProducts components, then to Product component:

```
<ListOfProducts products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart}/>
```

4- passing myCart to Cart component:

```
{myCart.length > 0 && <Cart myCart={myCart}/>}
```

5- my implementation of the Cart component:

```
function Cart(myCart) {
  
  return(
    <form className="cart">
      <h2>My Cart</h2>
      <ul>
        {myCart.map((product, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {product.name} - Price: {product.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
}
```

the condition in step 4 is working correctly, the Cart component appears whenever I add a product, but when I did `console.log(typeof(myCart))` it prints `object` although the initial state is an empty array. where did I do it wrong?

**Edit:**
I've created a link of the full code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/kp4z5y?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0006356izogqsci5%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0002356id6j37pgp%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0003356i0skbnbf0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0005356iaqurbhch%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsd6xott0002356id6j37pgp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0002356id6j37pgp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd77iql009k356h3srfgsg6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsd77iql009k356h3srfgsg6%2522%257D%252C%2522clsd6xott0005356iaqurbhch%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0005356iaqurbhch%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsd77dso006w356h6dxfa0a9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd77dso006w356h6dxfa0a9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clsd6xott0003356i0skbnbf0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd6xott0003356i0skbnbf0%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsd77ah5005a356h0w5hsbv8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsd77ah5005a356h0w5hsbv8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: If `myCart.map` is not a function then `myCart` is not an array.  When you debug, what observed value does `myCart` have when the error occurs?  Can you provide a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David I know the meaning of the error, but I don't know where the type changed from an array to an object, I've set the initial value of the state of an empty array []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple mistake with using props:

```
function Cart(myCart) { //myCart is an object that holds your actual myCart property. (myCart.myCart). It is usually named "props" (props.myCart)

  
  return(
    <form className="cart">
      <h2>My Cart</h2>
      <ul>
        {myCart.map((product, index) => ( // in this case, what you need to use is myCart.myCart.map()
          <li key={index}>
            {product.name} - Price: {product.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
}
```

You probably meant to deconstruct the myCard property from props:
`function Cart({myCart})`

or use it like this

```
function Cart(props) {
  
  return(
    <form className="cart">
      <h2>My Cart</h2>
      <ul>
        {props.myCart.map((product, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {product.name} - Price: {product.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: OOH YOU'RE  RIGHT! I can't believe I've spent 4 hours to figure out what was the problem!! thank you very much for helping